# How to install PHP Xdebug in Eclipse on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, eclipse, xdebug

I have a PHP file and I want to debug that file in Eclipse. I have heard about Xdebug as the best way to debug a PHP file in Eclipse.

What are the steps needed to be able to debug PHP files in Eclipse? I am using Windows OS.

Comment: Install XDebug in Windows

– Create a php file with the code phpinfo().
– Open the newly created file in a browser. This outputs information about PHP’s configuration.
– Select All (CTRL + A)
– Copy (CTRL + C)
– Open http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php
– Paste in the textarea present in the page of the above link. Note: Do not paste the raw HTML (from view-source).
– Click ‘Analyse’ button.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download PHP for eclipse (PLUGIN eclipse)

Use update URL
https://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/7.0
[image: Here the PHP PDT plugin you need in eclipse]

2. Download XAMPP for windows and install it
   https://www.apachefriends.org/es/download.html

Now you can follow alternative instructions here or continue to the next point where i explain what you need to do.
http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug

After installing XAMPP you should start Apache
[image: XAMPP control interface]

Download Xdebug e.g http://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll  and check if it is correctly installed. Follow next instructions

```
1. Download php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll. 
2. Move the downloaded file to C:\xampp\php\ext
3. Update C:\xampp\php\php.ini and change the lines

    [XDebug]
    ;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
    ; zend_extension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
    ; Modify the filename below to reflect the .dll version of your xdebug
    zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.2-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
    xdebug.remote_enable=true
    xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1  ; if debugging on remote server,
                              ; put client IP here
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.profiler_enable=0
    xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"

4. Restart the XAMPP webserver in your XAMPP control Panel
```

Comment out any Zend Optimizer in php.ini because it is not compatible with XDebug. For example, all of this should be commented out (using “;”):
[Zend]

```
; zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\ZendExtensionManager.dll"
; zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts = "C:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\Optimizer"
; zend_optimizer.enable_loader = 0
; zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_optimizer.license_path =
```

Check that it is working with phpinfo. You go to your browser and go to:
http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php
Or create in your c:/xampp/htdocs
A file calling phpinfo e.g.
http://localhost/phpinfocall.php

[image: PHPINFO results for XDEBUG section]
[image: Where to edit your php code]

Configuration PHP debug in eclipse
You can create a PHP project. That project should be pointint to **C:\xampp\htdocs**

The C:\xampp\htdocs is the localserver root folder in xampp. Inside you can create subfolders.
[image: Rootfolder of localhost, here or on subfolder place your project]

Configure PHP Preference of eclipse
Connect eclipse with php parser of xampp

[image: Connect eclipse with php parser xampp]

Configure this and check that xdebug is detected in eclipse from xampp
[image: Checkxdebug connection]

How to create a debug view from a PHP file in your project
[image: Howtocreatea debug view from a PHP file in your project]

Debug view configuration below,
[image: Debug view configuration_1]
[image: Debug view configuration_2]

Lastly, you will see in the debug perspective, that the debugger stop automatically on the first line of your php file.

[image: Debug view first line breakpoint]

Comment: "one zend_extension parameter is possible." that's not true. You can have multiple (such as opcache and xdebug loaded) at the same time.

Comment: Corrected the "one zend_extension parameter is possible." with "remove the zenZend Optimizer" according to http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug